# iOS - database strategy for calendar based app

Tags: ios, database, swift, core-data

I'm trying to build an iOS app that allows data to be entered by the user based on the day you have selected from some sort of custom calendar view.

I only want to store user entries but this does mean that there can be up to 365 entries for any given year. Also, the entry will several fields and a subset of data for some of the fields too.

I'm not sure how to store this data in the most efficient way or by which means i.e. CoreData, plists etc...

Can anyone please advise me on a suitable approach to take?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using CoreData using Entity relationships. I only store the entries that the user physically enters and using some logic with NSCalendar and NSDate to populate the gap dates inbetween entries.